# Adding numbers up

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using an onChange Listener on a drop down menu, On change I want to add all the numbers up in totalCost variable, but the answer is **undefined20** or some other number. It doesn't add up.

```
<p id="test"></p>
   <p id="test2"></p>
   <select id="first" onChange="myFunction()">
   <option></option>
   <option value="20">Test1</option>
   <option value='100'>Test2</option>
   <option value='200'>Test3</option>

   </select>

    <script>
document.getElementById("test").onchange = function() {myFunction()};


function myFunction(){
     var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
     var totalCost;
     totalCost += x;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = totalCost;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: try initializing totalCost: `var totalCost = 0;`

Comment: And why were you not able to find this simple error by yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined20` is the result of:

```
totalCost += x
```

Because the variable, `totalCost` isn't initialized with a value; to correct that you only need to use:

```
var totalCost = 0;

totalCost += parseInt(x, 10);
```

The reason for `parseInt()` is that all HTML attributes are considered strings by default, and must - if you want a number - be converted to a number using either:

- `+x` (unary `+` operator),
- `Number(x)`,
- `parseInt(x, 10)` (`10` is the numerical base, ten for decimal-based numbers),
- `parseFloat(x)`.

```js
document.getElementById("test").onchange = function() {
  myFunction()
};


function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value,
      totalCost = 0;
  totalCost += parseInt(x, 10);
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = totalCost;
}
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
<p id="test2"></p>
<select id="first" onChange="myFunction()">
  <option></option>
  <option value="20">Test1</option>
  <option value='100'>Test2</option>
  <option value='200'>Test3</option>

</select>
```

References:

- [`Number()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [Unary `+` operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6).

Comment: Missing link: [*Unary + operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6). There is also the [*Number* constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.1) called as a function: `Number(x)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: thanks! I've never found a good reference for the unary `+` operator until now; and I've edited to add that, and the `Number(x)` into the answer. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: If no other operation needs to be done, you could assign `myFunction` directly to the `onchange` event, instead of wrapping it inside an anonymous function. **Edit** : @DavidThomas Fair enough ;)

Comment: @blex: indeed, I just felt it was tangential to the problem (and, honestly, didn't want to go too far into the dark, given the OP's apparent new-comer status).